# Changing default rollbackFor behaviour for any Exception

Tags: spring

By default, Spring's `Transactional` annoation won't rollback on checked exceptions.

One can use `Transactional`'s `rollbackFor` attribute to override this.

Is it possible to override this behaviour globally rather than on each annotation?

I have methods that throw IOException. A possibility could be wrapping those exceptions in `RuntimeException`, as they are unrecoverable for my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches that I am aware of:

1. [Create your own Meta-Annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-custom-attributes) that handles your particular
   transaction semantics
2. Write an aspect (either [around](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice) or [after-throwing](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-advice-after-throwing)) that wraps all checked exceptions in RuntimeExceptions